# Wrong html table layout with columns attached

Tags: html, html-table

I'm new to the html language.

I would like to better set the table below because because the data is seen all attached, I would like to divide the columns and set the text of each line in the central position

```html
<html>

<body class="text-center">
  <form>
    <table class="table-ext" border='1'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Servizio</th>
          <th>Descrizione</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">
            <div class="divinterno">
              <table class="table-int">
                <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>searchCostruttore</td>
                  <td>servizio che serve per ottenere il costruttore tramite sigcos e dessig</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>searchStructureAgent</td>
                  <td>servizio che serve per ottenere la struttura dell'agente tramite codice e descrizione</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>getStructureAgent</td>
                  <td>servizio che serve per ottenere la struttura dell'agente tramite il codice</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>4</td>
                  <td>searchCondizioniBancarieClienteOasi</td>
                  <td>servizio che serve per ottenere le condizioni bancarie del cliente Oasi tramite codice cliente</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>5</td>
                  <td>searchAgent</td>
                  <td>servizio che serve per ottenere l'agente tramite codcon e descra</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>6</td>
                  <td>getGruppo</td>
                  <td>servizio che serve per ottenere le informazioni riguardanti il gruppo tramite sigcos e codgru</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>7</td>
                  <td>searchPayment</td>
                  <td>servizio che serve per ottenere il pagamento tramite pagame e despag</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>8</td>
                  <td>getSottoGruppo</td>
                  <td>servizio che serve per ottenere le informazioni riguardanti il sottogruppo tramite sigcos, codgru e codsgr</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>9</td>
                  <td>getArticolo</td>
                  <td>servizio che serve per ottenere le informazioni riguardanti l'articolo tramite codint, coarfo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>10</td>
                  <td>getFido</td>
                  <td>servizio che serve per ottenere il fido tramite cliente, dataat e datafi</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>getPayment</td>
                  <td>servizio che serve per ottenere il pagamento tramite il codice</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>12</td>
                  <td>getAgent</td>
                  <td>servizio che serve per ottenere l'agente tramite il codice</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>13</td>
                  <td>searchGruppo</td>
                  <td>servizio che serve per ottenere il gruppo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>14</td>
                  <td>searchZona</td>
                  <td>servizio che serve per ottenere la zona tramite codice e descri</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>15</td>
                  <td>getCustomers</td>
                  <td>servizio che serve per ottenere le informazioni riguardanti tutti i clienti</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>16</td>
                  <td>getCustomer</td>
                  <td>servizio che serve per ottenere le informazioni riguardanti il cliente tramite il codice</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>17</td>
                  <td>getZona</td>
                  <td>servizio che serve per ottenere la zona tramite il codice</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>18</td>
                  <td>getCostruttore</td>
                  <td>servizio che serve per ottenere il costruttore</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>19</td>
                  <td>searchArticolo</td>
                  <td>servizio che serve per ottenere le informazioni riguardanti l'articolo tramite codint coarfo e descri</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>20</td>
                  <td>getFidoClienteOasi</td>
                  <td>servizio che serve per ottenere fidoclienteoasi tramite codice cliente</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>21</td>
                  <td>searchSottoGruppo</td>
                  <td>servizio che serve per ottenere le informazioni riguardanti il sottogruppo tramite sigcos,codgru,codsgr e dessgr</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>22</td>
                  <td>getArboAnagrafica</td>
                  <td>servizio che serve per ottenere l'anagrafica in arbo tramite il codice</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really solve the problem on your specific table but here is a simplified way of creating what you want.

```html
        <table style="width:100%" border="1">
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Servizio</th> 
            <th>Descrizione</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>searchCostruttore</td>
            <td>servizio che serve per ottenere il costruttore tramite sigcos e dessig</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>searchStructureAgent</td>
            <td>servizio che serve per ottenere la struttura dell'agente tramite il codice</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3
        </td>
            <td>getStructureAgent
        </td>
            <td>servizio che serve per ottenere la struttura dell'agente tramite il codice
        </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: with width:100%?